# jQuery mobile list with filtering: how to change the clear button text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I know there is a option to use for input field (data-clear-btn-text), but if i use automatic filtering in a listview jQuery mobile adds this input field automatically.
So what is the name of the property here?

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search fruits..." data-inset="true" data-clear-btn-text="test">
```

this sample doesn't work in jQM 1.3.2.

Comment: Ok, i found the solution: Script:    $('.ui-input-clear').attr('title', 'new title');

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for clear button, however you can override it using some JS and CSS.

That button is a normal button but with `data-iconpos="notext"`, so you need to override this using `.buttonMarkup()`. And then change text inside a `span` holding button's name/text.

```
$(".ui-input-clear").buttonMarkup({
  "iconpos": "left", // or right
    "mini": true // convert it into a small button
});

// change button's text
$(".ui-input-clear .ui-btn-text").css({
  "font-size": "12px",
    "padding-left": "0.5em"
}).text("Clear");

// override padding to keep it within input borders
$(".ui-input-clear .ui-btn-inner").css({
  "padding": "0.4em 1em 0.4em 1.5em"
});
```

**CSS**

```
// to adjust button's position
.ui-input-search .ui-input-clear {
  margin-top: -16px;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/br9FT/)**

Comment: @ahorak you're welcome. I'll keep my answer in case someone else is looking for a solution. You can post your solution as an answer, however, mine is different than yours, maybe I misunderstood what you wanted :)